# How do I align all the texts in the middle spread evenly, and have a button on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several  elements that I would like them to be shown in the middle of a div, spread evenly. Then I would like to have a button(or several) that are at the same line with the  elements, but aligned on the right side.

https://jsfiddle.net/Leptuc8m/2/

The elements are as follow:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="status">
    <span>content 1</span>
    <span>content 2</span>
    <span>content 3</span>
    <span>content 4</span>
    <div class="actions">
      <button>
      Do something
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

so far I can only have all of them evenly spread:

```
.status {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 20vw;
    padding-right: 20vw;
}
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: This what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/1sykc4p6/2/

Comment: You got it... Look up CSS position for more info on absolute and relative positioning... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The button is placed on the right side because you put:

```css
<div class="actions">
      <button>
      Do something
    </button>
  </div>
```

inside `<div class="status">`, therefore it must be in line with `content 1`, `content 2`, ... elements

To align the button below theses elements, you need to separate the button into a new div, e.x `div class="btn"` like that:

```css
<div class="btn">
    <div class="actions">
      <button>
      Do something
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
     <!--  <button>
      Do something
          </button> -->
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
     <!--  <button>
      Do something
          </button> -->
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
     <!--  <button>
      Do something
          </button> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]
Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8rz7vcw/13/). Hope this can help you to resolve your issue.